# How to use Canonical URL meta tag to avoid duplicate content issues with WP home pages

Tags: theme-development, wp-head

By default, Wordrpess sites have at least 2 URLs that can be used to reach the home page:

```
www.site.com/
www.site.com/hello-world
```

Both these URLs point to the same page, the default "hello world" post that WordPress creates.

How can theme developer's specify a canoninical url meta tag to suggest to search agents which URL it should index in the above example?

In your answer, please include an example for each choice: one in which site.com is preferred and one in which site.com/hello-world is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might probably want to install [Canonical URL’s for WordPress (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/canonical/). It allows you to specify a canonical URL for each post and page. So you can configure the way you want.

The plugin is not big, you probably can integrate the functionality easily into your theme then.